# Can continuation tokens be used for slightly different queries?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am using azure table storage and I wanted to know if I could use continuation tokens (provided in the REST APIs response to a query) with a slightly different query.

Example:

Get $top=1 of the entire table (which returns partition and row continuation tokens). On the next query, I want to get more, so I set $top=10. Can I provide the initial continuation tokens to skip the first result?

Comment: Gaurav, put your comment as an answer to get proper vote and to help closing the questions.